# $\zeta(-1)$ and $p$-adic numbers

Tags: riemann-zeta, p-adic-number-theory

I have only a lay person's understanding of p-adic numbers, where a fraction may have an 'infinitely large' p-adic number representation.  That got me thinking about $\zeta(-1)$= -1/12 being equal to the sum of the natural numbers.  Is there a way to understand the sum of the natural numbers converging to -1/12 in the p-adic sense?

Comment: No, $1+2+3+\cdots$ does not converge in $p$-adic numbers, because the terms do not converge to $0$ in $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: In fact $\zeta(s)$ is difficult, if not impossible, to define in $p$-adics, for any $s.$

Comment: And it is not really helpful to call $p$-adic numbers infinitely large. They can have infinitely many digits, but that does not correspond to meaning "large" in $p$-adic numbers. Is $1/3$ infinitely large because $1/3=0.3333\dots$ has infinitely many digits?

Comment: I also think it's unhelpful to think of "the sum of the natural numbers" converging to anything. $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$ is a true fact, but $\zeta(-1)$ is no longer equal to infinite sums of powers of integers (that only holds for $\zeta(s)$ when the real part of $s$ is greater than $1$).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: In $p$-adics triangular numbers tend to cluster around $-1/8$, not $-1/12$. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441577/1234-and-%e2%88%92%e2%85%9b#441585).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: actually, there are p-adic $L$-functions that try to give a $p$-adic meaning to some values of classical $L$-functions (of which $\zeta$ is the original example), for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_L-function . Unfortunately, this is a more involved construction than what the OP suggests (which, indeed, can’t work due, as your first comment points out).